# What to do with the dist/server after building the Angular 17 with SSR?

Tags: angular, deployment, build, server-side-rendering

I use Angular 17 with SSR, I give the build and in dist I see two folders: browser and server.
I am uploading the files inside the browser folder to the hosting environment and it is all good but there is certain data not coming in the source page and I think it is because I do nothing with the dist/server folder. What to do with it, do I have to upload it anywhere ?

I did some research but did not find anything helpful and clear.

Comment: server folder is for SSR (server side rendering), and browser folder is for SSG (static site generator), and they are 2 different approaches. you can choose one of them for your website/web app

Comment: what do you mean I can choose one ? you mean I can ignore the browser folder and only upload the server one ? and if I just upload the server folder, where ? in my hosting provider ? cpanel in public_html ?

Comment: yes if you chose SSR, you should ignore browser folder, and upload server folder to your hosting provider, but there's extra setup in order your website to work, such as ensure that node and npm are installed on your server. it depends non your hosting provider. you can search: "how to deploy Angular Server Side Rendering (SSR) app to Azure Web App service?". change "Azure web service" with your hosting

Comment: Got it. I managed to make it work using Heroku. Thanks a lot!!! after days of researching your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!